# Having Problems with importing xlwt?

Tags: python, import, xlwt

I am using Eclipse with the PyDev plugin. I am using xlwt which is for writing to an excel sheet. I have the xlwt library in my src file. I have another python file called gene_sorter.py where i try to import xlwt. using

```
import xlwt
```

I keep gettting back this error:

```
 File "C:\Documents and Settings\Ben Fossen\Pythonworkspace\MTBgenes\src\gene_sorter.py", line 1, in <module>
from xlwt import *

File "C:\Documents and Settings\Ben Fossen\Pythonworkspace\MTBgenes\src\xlwt\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from Workbook import Workbook
ImportError: No module named Workbook
```

I am new to using PyDev and eclipse so mabye I am making a simple mistake. I can't seem to see what I am doing wrong. I am using a new enough version of python so that shouldn't be a problem. Has anyone else had this problem it seems very strange?

Comment: Side note: Never use from module import *. Its very unpythonic and prone to cause problems

Comment: Do you have another xlwt--perhaps a module named xlwt.py--somewhere else on your path?

Comment: no i don't that is what makes it strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"New enough version of Python" could well be "too new"; please edit your question to show the actual version number. In future, don't be coy; save the time and energy of everybody (including yourself) by including such essential information in your question.

If you are trying to run it under Python 3.1:

- Don't bother; it's not supported (yet).
- Please say where you got the notion that it was supported on 3.X, so that it can be corrected.

Otherwise:

- Any particular reason why you wouldn't just run the Windows installer and install it in the default directory?

Comment: Yes I am using Python 3.0. I see thats my mistake i didn't read it carefully enough I just saw it was supported on 2.3+ and didn't see the 2.6 part. Thanks for catching that. No there is no particular reason, I will give that a try.

Comment: `xlwt` is also supported on 2.7 -- give that a go. In any case, Python 3.0 should be dead and buried; it was a proof of concept. Use 3.1 if you want to dabble in 3.X. Very few people will purport to support a package running under 3.0 -- the general chorus is "Update to 3.1".

Comment: Yes, `xlrd` is supported on Python 2.7.

Comment: @John Machin: the page for xlwt (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) says 2.3 - 2.6, in marked contrast to the page for xlrd which says 2.1 - 2.7. Since you say here that 2.7 *is* OK for xlwt, is the page out of date or has some problem come up on 2.7?

Comment: I installed a fork of xlwt called xlwt-future for Python 3.4 (64-bit) as discussed here (https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/pull/32)